# Python | Numpy array images transformations

Tags: python, numpy, rgb, yuv

I have a Numpy image array with shape `(1000, 50, 100, 3)` (`class 'numpy.ndarray'`) which is containing 1000 images RGB (height = 50, width = 100, channels = 3). I want to first convert the `RGB` values to `YUV` values and rescale them to obtain `yuv` values. A prototypical implementation of a pixel-wise converter is given below.

> **My question**: Is there a simple way how I can carry out this transformation?

```
def yuv(_pixel):
    R, G, B = _pixel[0], _pixel[1], _pixel[2]
    Y = 0.299 *  R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
    y = Y / 127.5 - 1
    u = (0.493 * (B - Y)) / 127.5 - 1
    v = (0.887 * (R - Y)) / 127.5 - 1
    return np.array([y, u, v])
```

Comment: Your function does not work. Where is the definition of `Y`? Is it `y`? @markuscosinus Well. The problem is the extremely inefficient process of looping over every pixel.

Comment: Did my solution work? If yes, you may accept and upvote it. This will also give some points to you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) ?

You could do:

```
images_yuv = np.apply_along_axis( yuv, -1, images_rgb)
```

edit: Mixed up the order of the arguments

Comment: This does not work. Even if you swap `images_rgb` with `yuv` to correctly pass the arguments, the result does not seem to be ok.

Comment: Changing the order of the arguments to `images_yuv = np.apply_along_axis(yuv, -1, imgs)` and reducing the sample size to 100 images (strangely 1000 images seems to be too much for `apply_along_axis` with 64GB of RAM), `np.apply_along_axis` is working quite well, even though it is really slow. So this also seems to be a good solution if performance is not crucial.

Comment: @Scotty1- indeed I mixed the order of the arguments, probably you need to cut by batch. It would be nice if the function could be applied inplace, since it is shape preserving but it does not look there a numpy builtin offering that.

Answer (score 1):

You can vectorize the conversion so that all R, G and B pixels are transformed at the same time with:

```
def yuv_vec(images):
    R, G, B = images[:, :, :, 0], images[:, :, :, 1], images[:, :, :, 2]
    y = (0.299 *  R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B) / 127.5 - 1
    u = (0.493 * (B - y)) / 127.5 - 1
    v = (0.887 * (R - y)) / 127.5 - 1
    yuv_img = np.empty(images.shape)
    yuv_img[:, :, :, 0] = y
    yuv_img[:, :, :, 1] = u
    yuv_img[:, :, :, 2] = v
    return yuv_img
```

To time the performance, I'll show a short nested loop implementation of the yuv function shown in the question:

```
def yuv(_pixel):
    R, G, B = _pixel[0], _pixel[1], _pixel[2]
    y = (0.299 *  R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B) / 127.5 - 1
    u = (0.493 * (B - Y)) / 127.5 - 1
    v = (0.887 * (R - Y)) / 127.5 - 1
    return np.array([y, u, v])

def yuvloop(imgs):
    yuvimg = np.empty(imgs.shape)
    for n in range(imgs.shape[0]):
        for i in range(imgs.shape[1]):
            for j in range(imgs.shape[2]):
                yuvimg[n, i, j] = yuv(imgs[n, i, j])
    return yuvimg
```

Some speed comparisons:

```
imgs = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(100, 50, 100, 3))
%timeit yuvloop(imgs)
# Out: 8.79 s ± 265 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
% timeit np.apply_along_axis(yuv, -1, imgs)
# Out: 9.92 s ± 360 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit yuv_vec(imgs)
# Out: 34.4 ms ± 385 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So this is **256 times faster** than looping over the pixels. Using `np.apply_along_axis` seems to be even slower. The result of all three is the same.
I reduced the size of the test sample to 100 images, otherwise testing would have been too slow.

Comment: A nit: `np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(100,50,100,3))` does the data generation in the correct shape, saves you the cost of large reshape.

Comment: Oh, nice to know! Thanks! I implemented it right away.