# numpy process across axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that converts an image in RGB to YCbCr.
The image is in hwc format, where h is height, w is width and c is channel.

I have a NumPy array that contains multiple images in RGB in the following format:

nhwc where n is the number of images.

I want to convert all the images from RGB to YCbCr. Instead of looping over n, what would be the correct way to do it?

```
#Function to convert RGB to YCrCb (img in hwc format)
def processimg(img):
    img = np.array(img).astype(np.float32)
    ycbcr = convert_rgb_to_ycbcr(img)
    return ycbcr

def convert_rgb_to_ycbcr(img, dim_order='hwc'):
    
    y = 16. + (64.738 * img[..., 0] + 129.057 * img[..., 1] + 25.064 * img[..., 2]) / 256.
    cb = 128. + (-37.945 * img[..., 0] - 74.494 * img[..., 1] + 112.439 * img[..., 2]) / 256.
    cr = 128. + (112.439 * img[..., 0] - 94.154 * img[..., 1] - 18.285 * img[..., 2]) / 256.
    
    return np.array([y, cb, cr]).transpose([1, 2, 0])
```

Comment: May be you should also include the function `convert_rgb_to_ycbcr()`. There might be a possibility to do the vectorization inside the function itself.

Comment: @swag2198 Thanks for the comment. Added the function convert_rgb_to_ycbcr

Comment: Thanks to @swag2198 for mentioning vectorization of the inner function. Found another post that does what I wanted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364535/python-numpy-array-images-transformations